# Erlang defin in case .. of

Tags: erlang, case

I have 2 define:

```
-define(LOGIN_PACKET, 1).
-define(LOGOUT_PACKET, 2).
```

An try to:

```
case func(...) of
   LOGIN_PACKET ->
               .....;
   LOGOUT_PACKET ->
               ......
end
```

But i get warning:

this clause cannot match because a previous clause at line 209 always matches.

Why? Can we use defines in case of in Erlang.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it like below

```
case func(...) of
   ?LOGIN_PACKET ->
               .....;
   ?LOGOUT_PACKET ->
               ......
end
```

Comment: You always have to prefix a macro name with `?` to expand it.

Comment: Yes.I have always used it to expand. :)

Comment: I was just commenting on *WHY* you prefix a macro with a `?`, to expand it. If you managed to expand a macro *without* prefixing it with `?` then I would be impressed. :-)

Comment: I dont think that is possible as erlang compiler needs '?' to expand macro.